# Importing customers from Magento 1.9.1.0 to 1.9.2.3

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, importexport

I have a production instance of Magento which is running on version **1.9.1.0,** and I have another instance of Magento which is running on version **1.9.2.3.**

I am trying to export customers from the production instance into the new instance from Magento admin panel **System=>Import/Export** Area.

When trying to import the CSV file into the new instance I face many errors mainly due to the emptiness of some columns such as postcode for some customer. so I have filled all of them with "0" values. And right now when I try to import I get the following error :
**"E-mail and website combination is not found in rows: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10......"**

**My Questions are:**

**What might be the problem due to? and how can I resolve this?**

**Can I achieve the same thing by importing the customer tables via PHPMyAdmin instead of Magento admin panel?** **If yes, Do I need to import all tables that start with **customer_**?**

Comment: Have you tried from data-flow import/export?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri, No I have not. I go Import/Export tab and I choose Export, and then I export everything there. Do you suggest to try from data-flow?

Comment: Yes, that should help.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri, Thank you! your comment was the answer to my question.

Comment: Glad it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to import all the customers by following @AdarshKhatri comment.

Instead of going to **Magento Admin System=>Import/Export=>Import** I had to go to **System=>Import/Export=>Data flow**.

The rest of the steps are pretty much straight forward. First I exported the csv file from the export action in **Data flow** and then I imported that csv file using **Data flow** area again.